# Incidence Geometry

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Consider a quadraple $(a,b,c,d)$ of points in the real plane such that $|ab| = |cd|$. If the perpendicular bisector of line segment $ac$ is parallel to perpendicular bisector of $bd$, then how does one see that there exists a unique translation that maps $a$ to $c$ and $b$ to $d$ ?